# When I open my XCode projects, all the code is missing since I did a software upgrade

Tags: xcode

Since I upgraded months ago I've been unable to view any code when I open any of my XCode projects. Apple help have been useless, after 8 people, and approx. 30 hours I still can't seem to get through to the right department, and you have to write a complaint (the old fashioned way). I still can't believe a tech giant like Apple has such poor support and complaints processes. Please could someone help? I've removed any GitHub accounts and created a new folder for my files, and still can't seem to view anything. Current version of XCode is 11.5

Comment: Can you create a new Xcode project and add code to it ?

Comment: Yes I can create from scratch